# How to see or prove $L_p(\mathbb R^{n+1})= t^{-\frac{n+1}{p}}L_p(\mathbb R_+\times S^n ,\frac{dt}{t}d\phi)$

Tags: integration, lp-spaces, polar-coordinates

How to see or prove $L_p(\mathbb R^{n+1})= t^{-\frac{n+1}{p}}L_p(\mathbb R_+\times S^n ,\frac{dt}{t}d\phi)$. I know that i need to use change to polar coordinate because in all book says the same, $1<p<\infty$ and $S^n$ is the sphere unitary in $\mathbb R^n$.

I want to star taking one function $u$ in  $t^{-\frac{n+1}{p}}L_p(\mathbb R_+\times S^n ,\frac{dt}{t}d\phi)$ then $u(t,\phi)=t^{-\frac{n+1}{p}}\tilde{u}(t,\phi)$ with $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{S^n}|\tilde{u}(t,\phi)|^p\frac{dt}{t}d\phi<\infty$, how can transform this, what change of variable worth?

The idea is calculate
$$\int_{\mathbb R^{n+1}}|t^{-\frac{n+1}{p}}\tilde{u}(t,\phi)|^p dx= \int_{\mathbb R^{n+1}}|t^{-(n+1)}||\tilde{u}(t,\phi)|^p dx$$
i do not how is $dx$ and how transform the variable $(t,\phi)\in \mathbb R_{+} \times S^n$ in one variable $x\in R^{n+1}$, and perhaps apply Holder's inequality.

I was thinking in perhaps exist a stereographic representation  in $S^n$ as some day saw in calculus, with the pole $(0,0,1)$ and project one line between the pole and the points in the sphere unitary in $\mathbb R^3$ etc, please i want one hint, for me is important understand how to star please, thank you!!!

Comment: Scale the point $\phi$ by $t$ to get any point in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus 0$. No stereographic representation or inequalities needed.

Comment: @AHusain, thank you, i do not understand, when you said scale the point is something as  multiply  $\phi$ by $t$?Sorry you lost me

Comment: Yes. If you have $\phi$ as the embedded unit sphere $S^n$ inside $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. You have an off by one error in your second sentence. Consider the case $n=2$, where the usual sphere sits inside 3 dimensions.

Comment: I am processing your answer, i am still do not get it, but thank you,

Comment: Dear @AHusain , if i take $z=t\phi$ my new variable, i mean $(t,\phi)\rightarrow z$ then $dz=t^nd\phi$ and $t=\frac{z}{\phi}$ that is the way? sorry again

Comment: $\phi$ is not a single variable unless you are in $2$ dimensions. If you are thinking formulaicly rather than geometrically it may be better for you to write out the $n$ coordinates that make up $\phi$. Like there are $(\theta , \phi)$ for the $S^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132324/discussion-between-weymar-andres-and-ahusain).